# How to send firebase token to backend server from android studio

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, progressive-web-apps

i have a react web app and using it as mobile app and for push notifications i am using firebase and achieved it with firebase console and i want to send the notifications from backend server but i am a newbie in android studio so i am not able to figure out how to send the firebase token to backend server in a private api call.my user data is in redux store and i have to make a private api post request in my FirebaseMessagingService file.
any help will be greatly appreciated.

below is my code from FirebaseMessagingService file

```
package com.example.goldfish;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    public void showNotification(String title, String message){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifications")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message);
        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(999, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/08eb4bde835d629ada1765a8ea4b77c9e23daa06/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java) or you can get token like this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/08eb4bde835d629ada1765a8ea4b77c9e23daa06/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MainActivity.java#L101-L118)

Comment: Are you using firebase cloud messaging??

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes i am using fcm

Comment: Then you don't need to code to get notifications. Just add the firebase messaging dependency and post a notification from Firebase console

Comment: @Dharmaraj,i have achieved it but i want to send notifications from backend server but i don't know how to make a post api with the user data and fcm token from android studio to backend server

Comment: SO you want to send notifications using firebase cloud functions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
        public void onNewToken(String token) {
            super.onNewToken(token);
        //sendYourTokenToServer(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).